# Code coverage for cypress component tests in an Nx Angular Monorepo?

Tags: angular, components, cypress, code-coverage, nrwl-nx

I've set up an NX monorepo with an Angular application and two libraries: `mylib-a` and `mylib-b`. Each library has a single component (`TitleWidget` in `mylib-a` and `TitleWidgetB` in `mylib-b`). Each of these components has its own set of Cypress component tests. I can run the tests for each library separately, but I'm struggling to figure out how to instrument my source code and further get a combined test coverage report for both components.

You can find the sample app and instructions on how to run it here: https://github.com/rtm-celum/angular-cypress-component-test-coverage

I followed the cypress E2E code coverage guide (https://docs.cypress.io/guides/tooling/code-coverage#E2E-and-unit-code-coverage) and managed to install the plugin and everything around it.

I also tried to follow https://nx.dev/packages/angular/generators/cypress-component-configuration and to add instrumentation settings (`babel-loader`, `babel-plugin-istanbul`) as additional webpack configs via `cypress.config.ts` or via targets in my applications `project.json` file.

No matter what I tried, when I execute the cypress component tests, the `.nyc_output/out.json` always was empty `{}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also had problems with the setup but finally I found a solution.

Here are the required steps:

1. Install some more dependencies:

   ```
   npm i @cypress/code-coverage @jsdevtools/coverage-istanbul-loader -D
   ```
2. Add a custom webpack config to cour project

   ```
   import * as path from "path";

   export const CoverageWebpack = {
       module: {
           rules: [
               {
                   test: /\.(js|ts)$/,
                   loader: '@jsdevtools/coverage-istanbul-loader',
                   options: {esModules: true},
                   enforce: 'post',
                   include: [
                       path.join(__dirname, '../..', 'apps'),
                       path.join(__dirname, '../..', 'libs')
                   ],
                   exclude: [
                       /\.(cy|spec)\.ts$/,
                       /node_modules/
                   ]
               }
           ]
       }
   };
   ```
3. Modify the cypress.config.ts like this:

   ```
    import {nxComponentTestingPreset} from '@nx/angular/plugins/component-testing';
    import {defineConfig} from 'cypress';
    import {CoverageWebpack} from './coverage.webpack'

    const nxPreset = nxComponentTestingPreset(__filename);

    export default defineConfig({
      component: {
        ...nxPreset,
      devServer: {
        ...nxPreset.devServer,
        webpackConfig: CoverageWebpack,
      },
      setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires
      require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config)
      // include any other plugin code...

          // It's IMPORTANT to return the config object
          // with any changed environment variables
          return config;
        },
      }
    });
   ```
4. Add following line to component.ts (thx @Miguel)

   ```
   import '@cypress/code-coverage/support'
   ```

Here is my result for mylib-a:
[coverage output html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPDws.png)

Unfortunately also the cypress commands will be listed. Maybe this can be solved by changing the include or exclude in the coverage.webpack.ts.

I hope I did not forget anything. (I cloned your project and modified it. If you create a branch for me I might push my changes inside it if you want.)

Comment: To remove cypress commands from code coverage:
[https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage#exclude-files-and-folders](https://github.com/cypress-io/code-coverage#exclude-files-and-folders)

I just added a .nycrc with:

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "\*\*/cypress/\*\*"
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm for React projects too, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've also been dealing with this issue.

The steps provided by @Butterbluemchen are similar to the ones I followed, you can find them [here](https://digitaldrummerj.me/cypress-code-coverage/).

I think it is missing adding

```js
import '@cypress/code-coverage/support'
```

in cypress/support/component.js

Anyway following any option mentioned here I'm still not getting the coverage report correct.
It is marking lines that don't correspond with the real source code but with minified or transpiled code executed by Cypress...

EDIT: I found my problem with the correct coverage report. The reason was the devServer started by NX for Cypress was not using soureMap. I just modified the `devServerTarget` option for the `component-test` tag in `project.json` to use the `development` configuration. Something like:

```json
"component-test": {
  "executor": "@nx/cypress:cypress",
  "options": {
    "cypressConfig": "libs/mylib-a/cypress.config.ts",
    "testingType": "component",
    "skipServe": true,
    "devServerTarget": "mylib-a:build:development"
  }
}
```